# How to read jsonl.gz file stored in an s3 bucket using Boto3-Python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, gzip, boto3

I have a few files in my s3 bucket that is stored as .GZ files. I am using boto3 to access those file and I am trying to read the file's contents.

However, I keep getting this error when I run my code:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] read() on write-only GzipFile object
```

**Here is my code:**

```
    import boto3
    import os
    import json
    from io import BytesIO
    import gzip
    from gzip import GzipFile
    from datetime import datetime
    import logging
    import botocore
    
    # AWS Bucket Info
    BUCKET_NAME = '<my_bucket_name>'

    #My bucket's key information to where the .GZ files are stored
    key1 = 'my/path/to/file/shar1-jsonl.gz'
   # key2 = 'my/path/to/file/shar2-jsonl.gz'
   # key3 = 'my/path/to/file/shar3-jsonl.gz'
    
    # Create s3 connection
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
   
    zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME, key=key1)
    buffer = BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
    
    z = gzip.open(buffer,'wb').read().decode(('utf-8'))
```

Is there any way to collect the jsonl.gz file and then read its contents using boto3? I am new to boto3 and gzip files so any ideas or suggestion would help

Comment: You are passing `wb` to `gzip.open`. The "w" means write mode.

Comment: But when I switch it to rb.. it just shows b'' when I print it